# Вернуть ответ в формате json

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

У меня есть RestController который делает POST и GET. Мне нужно чтобы возращаемые данные у меня отображались как json.

```
public List<Persons> Names_List = new ArrayList<>();
@RestController
public class Post_Get {

public List<String> Names_List = new ArrayList<>();

@PostMapping(value = "api/names")
public String post (@RequestParam(value = "username", required = true, defaultValue = "None") String names) {
    Names_List.add(names);
        return " Saved:" + names;
}

@GetMapping(value = "api/names", produces = "application/json")
public String get(String result) {
        return "Names - " + Names_List.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@PostMapping(value = "...", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`. `@GetMapping` аналогично. После чего `return`-ом возвращаешь обычный POJO

Upd: Ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так (не проверял, может где-то описка. Но суть должна быть понятна)
Person

```
public class Person {
    public String name; // Тут должен быть private, гет/сет методы и конструктор с именем. Пишу так с целью сокращения объема кода в примере.
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostMapping(value = "api/persons", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Person post (@RequestParam("username") String name) {
        Person person = new Person(name);
        persons.add(person);
        return person;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "api/persons", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Person> get() {
        return persons;
    }
}
```

Comment: к примеру так возращать POJO обьект? `Persons persons = new Persons();
        persons.setName(Names_List.toString());
            return "Names - " + persons;`

Comment: @Alex нет. К примеру `return persons;` В вашем случае, вы пытыетесь вернуть строку. Не надо так.

Comment: но `return persons` у меня не срабатывает. Я создаю класс `Persons` , там поле `name` и записываю в него `Names_List`, а потом просто вывожу `return persons`, так?

Comment: @Alex `public String post` поменяй на `public Persons post`. И в get так же

Comment: @Alex у вас проблемы с ООП. Вам нужен `List<Person>...`, в каждом `Person` есть поле `String name`, и вернуть, по хорошему, нужно весь лист

Comment: можете написать код, если не сложно, ибо что-то у меня не то выходит

Comment: @Alex добавил в ответе

Comment: Огромная вам благодарность, очень выручили. 2 дня сидел думал, а тут все просто оказывается

Comment: @Alex всё просто, если не усложнять :)